# How to create unique property in a child class?

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to extend the class Person to Student and Employee child classes. Is there a way where I can create the unique properties **Course** and **Department** to the *Student* and *Employee* respectively *without repeating* the declaration of the properties of the parent class using the `__init__()`?

Here is the code:

```
class Person():
   def __init__(self, name, address):
       self.name = name
       self.address = address
       
class Student(Person):
   stud_id = 0
   def __init__(self, course):
       Student.stud_id += 1
       self.course=course
       
   def show(self):
       print(self.stud_id)
       print(self.name)
       print(self.address)
       print(self.course)
       
class Employee(Person):
   emp_id = 0
   def __init__(self, department):
       Employee.emp_id += 1
       self.department=department

   def show(self):
       print(self.emp_id)
       print(self.name)
       print(self.address)
       print(self.department)

stud = Student("Josh", "Philippines", "StudCourse")
stud.show()

emp = Employee("Claire", "Australia", , "EmpDepartment")
emp.show()
```

Comment: It sounds like you just want to assign to `self.course` and `self.department` in the Student and Employee `__init__` functions. Also, I don't think your `stud_id` and `emp_id` variables do what you intended them to do. You're not setting a unique id per student and employee, you're keeping a count of how many there are.

Comment: Also please note the typo in `__int__` (missing `i`)

Comment: @Tomerikoo, the solution presented in that post using the __init__() in the child class where the attributes name and phone are repeatedly declared/overridden, is what I am trying to ask. Do we really need to repeat declaring the attributes of the Parent class in the child class? Because I am trying to add a unique attribute for the child class - course and department for the Student and Employee child classes respectively.

Comment: They are repeated in the question. Did you look at the first answer that suggests how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [super()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super). Please see below:

```
class Person():
   def __init__(self, name, address):
       self.name=name
       self.address=address

class Student(Person):
   stud_id=0
   def __init__(self, name, address, course):
       self.stud_id = Student.stud_id
       Student.stud_id +=1
       super().__init__(name, address)
       self.course = course

   def show(self):
       print(self.stud_id)
       print(self.name)
       print(self.address)
       print(self.course)

class Employee(Person):
   emp_id=0
   def __init__(self, name, address, department):
       self.emp_id = Employee.emp_id
       Employee.emp_id +=1
       super().__init__(name, address)
       self.department = department

   def show(self):
       print(self.emp_id)
       print(self.name)
       print(self.address)
       print(self.department)

stud = Student("Josh", "Philippines", "StudCourse")
stud.show()

emp = Employee("Claire", "Australia", "EmpDepartment")
emp.show()

stud2 = Student("Josh 2", "Philippines 2", "StudCourse 2")
stud2.show()

emp2 = Employee("Claire 2", "Australia 2", "EmpDepartment 2")
emp2.show()
```

which gives me following output:

```
0
Josh
Philippines
StudCourse
0
Claire
Australia
EmpDepartment
1
Josh 2
Philippines 2
StudCourse 2
1
Claire 2
Australia 2
EmpDepartment 2
```